# Pandas - Count row with a specific value when grouped

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a certain use case and I cannot do it well in pandas.

```
order_id  asset_id
1         A
1         B
1         C
2         A
2         C
3         A
4         B
4         C
```

1. I would like to know in how many orders I have the asset `A` **alone**? In that case: 1 time (In order 3)
2. I would like to know in how many orders I have the asset `A` **with others**? In that case: 2 times (In order 1 and 2)

It could be great to have some help with that. I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: `A` alone means only one 'A' ? or  include 'A' + 'A'?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that. It will never be two times `A` in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need count unique values membership per groups `order_id` first aggregate `set`s and then compare values by set `A`:

```
s = df.groupby('order_id')['asset_id'].agg(set)
print (s)
order_id
1    {A, B, C}
2       {A, C}
3          {A}
4       {B, C}
Name: asset_id, dtype: object

alone = (s == {'A'}).sum()
print (alone)
1

with_others = (s > {'A'}).sum()
print (with_others)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) operations:

```
(df.groupby('order_id')['asset_id']
   .agg(alone=lambda x: set(x)=={'A'},
        others=lambda x: set(x)>{'A'}
       )
   .sum()
)
```

Output:

```
alone     1
others    2
dtype: int64
```